# HTTP 500 Internal Server Error in WebGL version

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api, unity-webgl

I have my own ASP.net Web API 2 server with Entity Framework, which is hosted on Azure. It connects a database from Azure and creates controllers for GET and POST requests. DTOs were also created. There is also an application on Unity, which connects to the server and sends him requests in the form of logs about various conditions. In the standalone version, everything works fine, but if you do this in the WebGL version, and throw it on the hosting, it gives (500 internal server error). And I don’t know what could be the problem

GET on server:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Rooms))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetRoom(string id)
    {
        Rooms room = db.Rooms.Where(r => r.RoomName == id).FirstOrDefault();
        var roomdto = new RoomDto(room);
        if (roomdto == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(roomdto);
    }
```

DTO example:

```
    public class RoomDto
{
    public int IDRoom { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }

    public RoomDto(Rooms entity)
    {
        IDRoom = entity.IDRoom;
        RoomName = entity.RoomName;
    }
}
```

My DB:

```
   public partial class LogsDBModel : DbContext
{
    public LogsDBModel()
        : base("name=DBModel")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Ball> Ball { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DirectionVector> DirectionVector { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GameTime> GameTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Impact> Impact { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Players> Players { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Rooms> Rooms { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<database_firewall_rules> database_firewall_rules { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GameTime>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Ball)
            .WithOptional(e => e.GameTime)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Players>()
            .Property(e => e.PlayerName)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Rooms>()
            .Property(e => e.RoomName)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Rooms>()
            .HasMany(e => e.GameTime)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Rooms)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Rooms>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Players1)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Rooms)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<database_firewall_rules>()
            .Property(e => e.start_ip_address)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<database_firewall_rules>()
            .Property(e => e.end_ip_address)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

Get from Unity:

```
     public IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(Host + uri))
        {
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
            response = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator GetID(string entity, string identify)
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(GetRequest(entity + identify));
    switch(entity)
    {
        case "Rooms/":
            Rooms room = Rooms.CreateFromJSON(response);
            ID = room.IDRoom;
            break;
        case "Players/":
            Players player = Players.CreateFromJSON(response);
            ID = player.IDPlayer;
            break;
        case "DirectionVectors/":
            DirectionVectors dv = DirectionVectors.CreateFromJSON(response);
            ID = dv.IDDirectionVector;
            break;
        case "GameTimes/":
            GameTimes gt = GameTimes.CreateFromJSON(response);
            ID = gt.IDGameTime;
            break;
    }
}
```

Json:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Rooms
{
    public int IDRoom;
    [System.NonSerialized]
    public string RoomName;
    public static Rooms CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<Rooms>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The specified policy origin 'https://newlogsserverapi20200402121056.azurewebsites.net/' is invalid. It must not contain a path, query, or fragment.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute.ValidateOrigins(IList`1 origins)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute.GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.d__4.MoveNext()"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was in the wrong address when specifying CROS

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("https://newlogsserverapi20200402121056.azurewebsites.net", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Your WebGL Build file might be too big.** (This would mean that your game project is too big) To verify if that is the case, put
   your zip file on this page: [The upload game webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDTjq.png) *(*The max
   size is 100MB*)*
2. To access the *upload game webpage*, go to play.unity.com and press a button that
   looks like this on the navbar: [The button to press when on
   play.unity.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZzIG.jpg)
3. Here is a video demonstrating a simple, but effective, way to reduce the size of your game project: **youtu.be/7O21c8BzEzM**

This is a problem that I had before, I hope this helps anyone with a similar predicament.

Comment: Here is a video demonstrating a simple, but effective, way to reduce the size of your game project: https://youtu.be/7O21c8BzEzM